# PHP - variable not "resetting" during same session

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7, civicrm

I've been working to bridge Joomla and CiviCRM profile updates. Initially, all I want to do is update the CiviCRM matching profile when the Joomla profile e-mail changes (Note: The latest civi version will update Joomla profile e-mail when civi e-mail changes...so that side is covered). With that, I have code that will work. That is, it will update civi e-mail properly when I manually fire the code from inside an authenticated session. Now I am trying to embed this code in the Joomla user_profile plug-in so that when a user changes their e-mail it will update civi e-mail.

Note: I know not to hack the core code. Ultimately, I will create a new profile plugin with my custom code, but for simplicity during development I'm using the core user_profile plugin. Anyone reading this, do not use the code below in production! It's incomplete and the core should not be hacked.

This works, however I've found that if the user does not logout of the session and then changes the e-mail a second time in the same session the newest e-mail is not recognized (the old e-mail is used), but if the user logs out and then logs in, changes e-mail, it will work. I hope that makes sense.

The problem must have something to do with the "instance" of the variable or something to that effect, but I'm new new to PHP coding and not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I've placed my custom code inside the function onUserAfterSave in the profile.php script of user_profile plugin.

Any PHP programmers know how I can fix this problem so that my custom code below will fire EVERY time the e-mail is changed in Joomla whether it's during the same session or not?

My code:

```
function onUserAfterSave($data, $isNew, $result, $error)
    {
            $userId = JArrayHelper::getValue($data, 'id', 0, 'int');

   // *** Truncating function code to de-clutter
   //         .
   //         .
   //         .

/*****************************************************
* Begin my custom code to save data to civi.
*****************************************************/

      require_once '/var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php';
      require_once          '/var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php';
      require_once '/var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/UFMatch.php';
      require_once '/var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php';
      require_once('/var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php');

      $t911_config     = CRM_Core_Config::singleton( );
      $t911_user       = JFactory::getUser();
      $t911_ufID       = $t911_user->id;
      $t911_ufUSER   = $t911_user->username;
      $t911_ufEMAIL  = $t911_user->email;             //this variable only sets on each login session
      $t911_ufTYPE   = $t911_user->usertype;
      $t911_ufGUEST = $t911_user->guest;
      $t911_contactID = CRM_Core_BAO_UFMatch::getContactId($t911_ufID);
      $t911_query  = "select email from civicrm_email where contact_id = $t911_contactID";
      $daoResult =& CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery( $t911_query, $t911_params);
      $daoResult->fetch();

      if ( $daoResult->email <> $t911_ufEMAIL )
      {
              CRM_Core_BAO_UFMatch::updateContactEmail($t911_contactID,$t911_ufEMAIL);
      }

/*****************************************************
 * End my custom code to save data to civi.
 ****************************************************/

   //         .
   //         .
   //         .
   // *** The remainder of the function code

            return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JFactory:getUser() is retrieving the user object from the session. This means that it only reads from the database when the session is empty, i.e. after each login. The problem you describe is consistent with the user email not being saved into the session after it was saved to the DB, so it always uses the value that was read at login.

Rather than using the session, try this:

```
$t911_user = new JUser($userId);
```

which will actually load direct from the database and get the values that were just saved.